# Plugging in a custom command to vim/fzf

Tags: vim, fzf, vim-fzf

I have created a command that lists "interesting" files. The output is a list of file names separated with new lines (much like the output of `grep -l`). The command is called `lif` - for 'list interesting files'.

I would like to use this command with the fzf plugin in vim, that is - after typing:

```
  :Lif
```

at the vim prompt, I would like to see a list of files and a file preview window, much like

```
  :Ag searchstring
```

or

```
  :Rg searchstring
```

give me a list of files matching searchstring and their preview. (The only difference being, I do not have to specify the searchstring.)

How can I plug `lif` into `vim/fzf`?

Comment: What did you [try](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#advanced-customization)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had tried a few things before asking (vim functions, different environment variables etc.) I need to dive into it then.